# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una Integracion de Calendly con Next13?

Tags: nextjs13

quisiera saber si alguien conoce una integración posible entre Calendly y Next 13. Por lo que veo se puede hacer con React, pero no encontré una manera de hacerlo con Next.js 13. Si alguien puede ayudarme con eso lo agradecería.
Saludos

Probé usar next/scripts pero no funciona. O quizas lo est[e haciendo mal.